# XML files .bat extract not working properly due to colon

Tags: xml, batch-file

I'm having a problem with my batch script. I am trying to extract the time & date but due to the colon it gives me an incomplete date & time.

Here's the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:<>" %%a, in ('findstr "xxxxxxxxxxxName=\"PHIL\" XXXXXXXX=\"Executive13\"" *.xml') do (
   set "list=%%b"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in (^"!list: ^=^
% Do NOT remove this line %
!^") do set %%c
   if "!xxxxxxxxxxxName!+!XXXXXXXX!" equ ""PHIL"+"Executive13"" (
      echo File: "%%a", date=%%~ta", testDuration=!testDuration!, holidayCount=!holidayCount!, lockTime=!lockTime!"
   )
)) > Outputfile.txt
start notepad outputfile.txt
```

The time is dated in XML files as:(extracted from"lockTime"):

```
 <testInfo testDuration="57" holidayCount="0" completedtask="12" XXXXXXXXXXName="PHIL" testVersion="13" lockTime="2017-04-11T11:20:05" 
    <result testStepName="locating" sequenceNrResult="1" testStepResult="OK">
    etc.
    </testInfo>
</testresult>
```

How do I fix this problem with the colon?

Output file always looks like this:

```
lockTime="2017-04-11T08"
```

Comment: Please show us some unprocessed data lines from the `findstr` command.

Comment: My guess is you either need to remove `:` from your first `for /f` statement's `delims=` clause, or use `date=%%~ta:%%~tb`.  More context with the XML would probably help if this is not the case.

Comment: My suggestion would be to ditch the string manipulation hack and use a tool that actually understands XML. Something like xmllint with an xpath run from a .bat would be way better.

Comment: @DanielHaley OP could probably also use the `[xml]` type accelerator in PowerShell and not even have to bother with 3rd party executables.  Something like `powershell "([xml](gc xmlfile.xml)).SelectSingleNode('//*[@lockTime]').lockTime"`, assuming `lockTime` is an element attribute and not a text node.

Comment: @rojo - very nice! (I'm not a powershell user so thanks for sharing.) I'd up vote that if it was an answer.

Comment: I updated the unprocessed data lines. Furthermore I tried to remove : or use date=%%~ta%%~tb. It will show me the lock time but then it won't show the modified date anymore. :( Moreover I never used powershell before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture this with a `for /f` loop:

```perl
powershell "([xml](gc xmlfile.xml)).SelectSingleNode('//*[@lockTime]').lockTime"
```

... and that'll scrape the `lockTime` value from the first XML node containing a `lockTime` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

try with [xpath.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)

```
call xpath.bat locktime.xml "//@lockTime"
```